# Preventdefault not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys am new to javascript web development.I have been through `preventDefault()` through my code.But when i used it it returns the error ..My code

```
<html>
<body>
function preventDef(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

 document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", 
preventDef(event),false);

</script>

<a href="www.google.com">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i use this code  and clicked on the link it redirects me to google.com ..what i need is the event must be blocked my `preventDefault()` function..

Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks

Comment: *"But when i used it it returns the error"* are you telling us which error or do we have to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `preventDef` function instead of passing it by reference.

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", preventDef, false);
//                                                              ^^^ don't call the function
```

EDIT: Another issue is that you are running this before the DOM is ready. You need to move the `<script>` tag down to be after the `<a>`.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">click here</a>
<script>
// ^^ did you miss an opening script?
function preventDef(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

 document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", preventDef, false);
//                                                              ^^^ don't call the function

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it didnt helped me ..still its redirecting to google

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @user See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @user3760836 Updated the answer with the rest of the fix.

Comment: @Scimonster i didnt get you ..it didnt work for me ..it would be helpful if you post the exact code ..

Comment: This one helped me ..:)